# SPA $http POST компонентный метод построения

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http, spa

хотел спросить, что я делаю не так, `method : 'POST'` я получаю `$scope.data.push(...) is not a function` но данные указанные в параметрах `"POST"` `data{...}` постятся как надо, а сервер выдает 201.

Вот мой template -

```
<div class="container create">
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>Creat invoice</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper form-container">
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="formNumber">Number:</label>
                        <input ng-model="invoice.number" type="text" class="form-control" id="formNumber" placeholder="Enter number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="formSupplyDate">Supplay Date: </label>
                        <input ng-model="invoice.date_supply" type="text" class="form-control" id="formSupplayDate" placeholder="Select date">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="formDate">Invoice Date: </label>
                        <input ng-model="invoice.date_due" type="text" name="Date" id="formDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Select date">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="formComment">Comment: </label>
                <textarea ng-model="invoice.comment" name="Comment" id="formComment" cols="50" rows="3" placeholder="Write..." class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="button-save d-flex justify-content-end">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addNewInvoice(invoice)" value="Save">
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот мой component -

```
    angular.module('addInvoices').component('addInvoices', {
    templateUrl: 'add-invoices/add-invoices.template.html',
    controller: ['$routeParams', '$http', '$scope', 
      function AddInvoicesController($routeParams, $http, $scope) {
        console.log('HELLOOO!');
        this.addInvoices = $routeParams.addInvoices;

        $scope.addNewInvoice = function(invoice) {
          $scope.date = new Date();
          console.log('HI MAN');
          $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'http://localhost:3000/invoices',
            data : {
              'number' : invoice.number,
              'comment' : invoice.comment,
              'date_supply' : invoice.date_supply,
              'date_created' : $scope.date,
              'date_due' : invoice.date_due
            }
          }).then(function(response){
            $scope.data = response.data;
            console.log(response);
            $scope.data.push(invoice.comment, invoice.number, invoice.date_supply, invoice.date_due, invoice.date_created);

          }, function(response){

          });
      };
      }
    ]
  });
```

Консоль выдает следующее `console.log(response.data);` после клика с введенными данными во все `input` выдает `$scope.data.push is not a function` [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь оставлю структуру своего SPA [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Итак, я выяснил, что не проходит клик по кнопке, не могу понять в чем причина, ведь на клике указан `$ctrl`

Comment: Не пойму, почему у меня не инжектится контроллер второй страницы??

Comment: Упрощу вам задачу и себе тоже, не пушатся данные 
`angular.js:14961 TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: `console.log($scope.data.push);` - получаю следующее - `{id: "7uaCr7J"}` - не совсем как бы то что мне нужно

Comment: Я своей строчкой push(...) почему то передаю только id которое генерируется автоматически.  Подскажите, хоть почему $scope.data.push(); not a function

Comment: как сервер твой post запрос обрабатывает и что возвращает?

Comment: @Grundy сервер в ответ на то что написано выше выдет `$scope.data.push is not a function` а в json все равно постится но только id - в консоли сервера вижу 201

Comment: `$scope.data.push is not a function` - выводит не сервер.

Comment: @Grundy это я знаю, но я не знаю как это фиксить...

Comment: чтобы пофиксить нужно знать что возвращает сервер: `response.data` - что приходит сюда

Comment: @Grundy `{id: "4hyEKXR"}`

Comment: @Grundy `console.log(response);` возвращает `{data: {…}, status: 201, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "Created", …}`

Comment: @Grundy я изменил в $http запросе `params{...}` на `data{...}` - сервер возвращает все тоже, но в JSON постится то как я указал в data

Comment: У вас в `response.data` не массив, а объект `{id: "4hyEKXR"}`. У этого объекта нет метода `push`. Как вы в темплейте планируете использовать `$scope.data`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko с `response.data` все впорядке так как я выше написал, что изменил `params: {...}` на `data: {...}` я получаю массив объектов

Comment: Обновите вопрос, покажите в вопросе текущий актуальный код. а также что сейчас находится в `response.data`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я обновил вопрос уже давно.

Comment: Прочитайте мой комментарий очень внимательно. У `response.data` нет метода `push`. Потому что `response.data` - это объект, а не массив!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у `response.data` нет метода `push`.

Потому что `response.data` - это объект, а не массив!

Пример, где `response.data` - объект. Данный код будет генерировать точно такую же ошибку, как у вас.

```js
const $scope = {};
const response = {};
const invoice = {
  comment: "",
  number: "",
  date_supply: "",
  date_due: "",
  date_created: ""
};
// объект, не массив
response.data = {
  number: 123121,
  comment: "Comment"
}
$scope.data = response.data;
console.log(response);
// вот здесь будет ошибка, т.к. у объекта нету метода push
$scope.data.push(invoice.comment, invoice.number, invoice.date_supply, invoice.date_due, invoice.date_created);
```

Судя по возвращаемым данным, вам надо сделать следующее.

```js
const $scope = {};
const response = {};
const invoice = {
  comment: "",
  number: "",
  date_supply: "",
  date_due: "",
  date_created: ""
};
// объект, не массив
response.data = {
  number: 123121,
  comment: "Comment"
}
$scope.data = response.data;
$scope.data.comment = invoice.comment;
$scope.data.number = invoice.number;
$scope.data.date_supply = invoice.date_supply;
$scope.data.date_due = invoice.date_due;
$scope.data.date_created = invoice.date_created;
console.log($scope.data);
```

Но на самом деле, надо понять, как вы будете использовать `$scope.data`, что бы дать точный ответ.

Comment: `{number: "", comment: "", date_supply: "", date_due: "", date_created: ""}` - вот что я получаю, то есть данные с `Input`ов не фиксируются

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич где вы это получаете? Вы с ошибкой `cannot read property 'push' of undefined` разобрались?

Comment: У меня нет данной ошибки, я выше привел фотографию, что у меня `$scope.data.push - not a function`

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Хорошо, вы разобрались с ошибкой `Uncaught TypeError: $scope.data.push is not a function`? Вам понятен мой ответ?

Comment: ваш ответ не не помог

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич если вы хотите, что бы вам помогли, будьте добры отвечать на **все** заданные вопросы, а не только на последний. Вопросы: 1) Вы разобрались с ошибкой `Uncaught TypeError: $scope.data.push is not a function`? 2) Как вы будете использовать `$scope.data`?

Comment: 1)  Я не разобрался с проблемой. Ваш ответ мне в этом не помог. 2) $scooe.data мне нужен для определения области видимости данных. Да я не понимаю к чему этот вопрос? На примерах кода чётко видно что я применяю его только здесь, для данного промежутка кода.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич у вас в примерах кода не видно, где и как вы его применяете в шаблоне. Это важно, понимать, какой тип вы там ожидаете. Судя по вашему желанию использования метода `push`, вам нужен массив. С другой стороны, судя по ответу вам все же нужен объект.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич прочитайте внимательно, пожалуйста. Я не спрашиваю, разобрались ли вы с проблемой. Я спрашиваю, **Вы разобрались с ошибкой Uncaught TypeError: $scope.data.push is not a function**. Ошибка не равна проблеме! Вам понятно, из-за чего ошибка происходит? Я в ответе подробно, с примерами кода это описал.